# React - Change URL for modal that can be open everywhere

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I'm new in React and I was asked to implement this feature in an App mostly done. So, I don't want to destroy everything.

I have a modal containing components login/register/activation/password-recovery/password-reset according the situation. This modal can appear on every single public page. It's possible to navigate in the modal from login to register, from login to password-recovery, from password-reset to login.
We can access to the modal from a link in he header and from other links through the site. The modal appears with an animated transition.

I was asked to change the URL according to the modal content displayed.

The URLs must be:

```
site.com/en/login 
site.com/en/register
site.com/en/activation
site.com/en/password-recovery
site.com/en/password-reset
```

The page behind the modal should remains even if the URL was `site.com/en/page1/info1/[...]` or the homepage should be displayed by default behind the modal on direct URL access/refresh.

I found many pieces for this puzzle on the web, but pieces don't seem to fit together. I just want to know the best way to achieve this task.

I don't have convincing code to show right now.

If that can help, it's a React-Redux App using JSX on NodeJS server.

Answer (score 0):

if your component is rendered via Router you can use `history.push()`, else you can wrap your component with `withRouter` from `react-router-dom` and then use `history.push()`,

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

const myComponent = () => {

   ...

}

// by this history is  going to be available from props in this component
export default withROuter(myComponent)
```

if neither of then was not working , you still have `location` object from `window` of browser left , try that....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the 'history' library can help you easily
https://www.npmjs.com/package/history

```js
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
const history = createHistory()

history.listen((location, action) => {
    // location is an object like window.location
    console.log(action, location.pathname, location.state)
})
```